# How does one end a function in dart similar to in JS typing return

Tags: dart

In `Javascript` when I want to end a function I usually write return, but in the dart, if I do that then the function asks for a return statement at the end of each branch which is messy.

```
Function createCategory(File image) {
    String title = _categoryTitle.value;
    if(image == null || title == null || title.length == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    CategoryModel newCategory = new CategoryModel();
    if(_categories.value == null) {
      _categories.sink.add([newCategory]);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

What is the correct way to do this in dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from that your method is valid Dart code but does not really do what I guess you think. Your method has the following signature:

```
Function createCategory(File image) {
```

This means your method is named `createCategory`, takes one argument of the type `File` and returns a `Function`. Since you have marked the method to return a `Function`, then Dart will tell you it is a problem if you just `return;` since this is properly not what you wanted.

If your method is not going to return any value, then you want to mark this with the return type of `void` like:

```
void createCategory(File image) {
  String title = _categoryTitle.value;
  if (image == null || title == null || title.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  CategoryModel newCategory = new CategoryModel();
  if (_categories.value == null) {
    _categories.sink.add([newCategory]);
  }
  return;
}
```

I should note, that the last `return` can be skipped since Dart will automatically add `return;` at the end of a function if it is missing.

Comment: thanks removing the Function and adding void made it work like i was expecting

Answer (score 0):

you can do that like this:

```
void createCategory(File image) {
    String title = _categoryTitle.value;

    if (image != null && title.isNotEmpty && _categories.value == null) {
        _categories.sink.add([CategoryModel()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i know i can do it like that but the problem comes when there are multiple if statements and i want to avoid using else blocks.  The point of the question is how to break the function not how it can be written without breaking the function

Comment: @AdamKatz sure. :)